# Find out if a date is more than 30 days old

Tags: python, datetime

I want to know if `insertion_date` is older than 30 days. This should detect down to the minute and second of the current time. The value in `insertion_date` will be dynamically pulled from an API.

Current code only detects up to the day, i need the accuracy to up to the second.

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

insertion_date = dateutil.parser.parse('2017-08-30 14:25:30')
right_now_30_days_ago = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)

print right_now_30_days_ago #2017-08-31 12:18:40.040594
print insertion_date #2017-08-30 14:25:30

if insertion_date > right_now_30_days_ago:
    print "The insertion date is older than 30 days"

else:
    print "The insertion date is not older than 30 days"
```

Comment: According to documentation, a timedelta is *A duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime instances **to microsecond resolution.***, therefore you have something wrong

Comment: Franco, I request you to reconsider your acceptance. This user has been caught plagiarising content on multiple occasions. I'm pretty sure this answer was also plagiarised in some form from another answer. Click on their profile and take a look.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you need to do something on similar lines:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time_between_insertion = datetime.now() - insertion_date

if  time_between_insertion.days>30:
    print "The insertion date is older than 30 days"

else:
    print "The insertion date is not older than 30 days"
```

Comment: Why is `timedelta` imported but never used?

Comment: This is wrong. `days` is an integer so it gives incorrect results for a 24 hour period after the 30th day starts

Comment: Why is it incorrect for a 24 hour period? When the 30th day starts, wouldn't the delta be days=29, hours=<greater-than-0>?

Comment: Thanks mate, it solved my issue for sure.

Answer (score 22):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print(datetime.now())
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 5, 7, 25, 37, 836117)

print(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30))
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 6, 7, 25, 51, 723674)
```

As you can see here, it is accurate down to seconds.

The problem is in `datetime.today()`. You should use `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.today()`:

```
time_since_insertion = datetime.now() - insertion_date

if time_since_insertion.days > 30:
   print("The insertion date is older than 30 days")
else:
  print("The insertion date is not older than 30 days")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The second example is wrong. `days` is an integer so it gives incorrect results for a 24 hour period after the 30th day starts

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Pandas in you project, you can do it pretty cleanly using the Timedelta's verbose string parsing. It also integrates nicely with datetime module:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

insertion_date = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1) # Your datetime here
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

if current_datetime - insertion_date < pd.Timedelta("30 days"):
    print("Inserted less than 30 days ago")
```

A nice thing is that you can easily modify that to include hours, seconds etc. if needed, for example `... <= pd.Timedelta("30 days 12 hours 30 minutes")`. This is not so easy with datetime module.