# How to compare ISO-8601 dates in python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I have a date in  ISO-8601  format

```
date="2018-03-13T17:22:20.065Z"
```

I want to find the current `UTC` time in `iso9621` format.
I found some code snippet like `datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()`

which gives us the following result

```
2018-06-12T08:19:28.954375
```

I want to find if the provided date is older than 30 days or not.

I tried to solve it as shown in this 
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046136/find-out-if-a-date-is-more-than-30-days-old/46046182)

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

insertion_date = dateutil.parser.parse('2018-03-13T17:22:20.065Z')
diffretiation=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() - insertion_date


print diffretiation 
print insertion_date

if diffretiation.days>30:
    print "The insertion date is older than 30 days"

else:
    print "The insertion date is not older than 30 days"
```

I found the following error here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    right_now_30_days_ago=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() - insertion_date
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Any help would be great here

Comment: I don't understand why you're converting one string to a date, and the other date to a string, and then subtracting them. You should do the string->date conversion and leave the other date as is.

Comment: I am confused about the solution what can be done here

Comment: Stop converting `diffretiation` to a string; remove the call to `isoformat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` is time zone unaware, and to make it aware use `pytz`:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import pytz

insertion_date = dateutil.parser.parse('2018-03-13T17:22:20.065Z')
diffretiation = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) - insertion_date


print diffretiation 
print insertion_date

if diffretiation.days>30:
    print "The insertion date is older than 30 days"

else:
    print "The insertion date is not older than 30 days"
#The insertion date is older than 30 days
```

P.S. `datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()` returns a string, and that was the error you encountered.